# Finding the index of an array element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an array of elements and I would like to get the index of the element that was clicked however in my code I keep getting the same value all the time. Even though through firebug I can see that all the elements are in the array. My code is below

The callback for the ajax call is below:

```
function featuredtrackscallback(rtndata) 
{ 
//$('#pagetitle').html("New Articles");
var data="";
for(j=0;j<=rtndata.length -1;j++)
{
    links[j] = "<li><a href='./player.html?id="+rtndata[j].track_id+"' data-transition='slide' id="+rtndata[j].track_name+"><h3>" + rtndata[j].track_name + "</h3><p><strong>" + rtndata[j].artist_name + "</strong></p><p>" + rtndata[j].genre_name + "</p></a></li>";
    $('#featurelist').append(links[j]);
}
$('#featurelist').listview('refresh'); 
}
```

In the `.done` section of the ajax call I am using this function

```
.done(function(){ 

        $('li').on('click', 'a', function () {
            alert(links.indexOf(this.li));

        });
```

When I click the link I only get the value -1 which is impossible. How can I get the index value of the link within the list view that was clicked by the user?

Comment: This doesn't look like a good approach. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Probably `this.li` is `undefined`, because normally there's no such property on any HTML element.

Comment: Even if you get it working, there's an apparent problem. The index within `links` is equal to the index within `rtndata`, which is not necessarily the index of the `<li>` element within its `<ul>`. This is because the LIs are appended without first clearing out the `<ul>`, so previously appended LIs will still exist. If I understand correctly, then you can use jQuery's `.index()` to discover the index of the clicked link's parent `<li>` within `#featurelist`. This appears to be what you want, though it's not clear why.

Comment: check the chat, tell me what you exactly need.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot when I check the links array in firebug it seems fine as `rtndata[j].track_id` is a value within a database table.

Comment: I added the following code and I get different values but it starts at 3 which is quite weird `$('li').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var index = $("a").index(this);
    alert(index);
   });`

Comment: Kern, it doessn't seem so weird when you understand the different forms of `.index()`. `$("a")` selects all `<a>` nodes on the page, including all those in which you are interested, plus any others. If `$("a").index(this)` gives values starting at 3, there must be three `<a>` links higher in the page than `#featurelist`. `.index()` without an argument behaves differently, returning the index of first element in the collection, from amongst its siblings. Try `var index = $(this).closest('li').index();`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot will do

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be looking for the index() method.

http://api.jquery.com/index/

You might also need the parent() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the big issue is that you're trying to match a DOM element to a string.  This won't work the way your script is written.

There are two fixes required to make this work.

The first is to take that DOM element and get the string version of it:

```
  $('li').on('click', 'a', function () {
     var match_string = $(this).parent().clone().wrap('<li/>').parent().html();
     alert( links.indexOf( match_string ) );
  });
```

The second requires changing the quotes used when you're setting up your array of `<li>`.  A DOM element put into string format uses double-quotes around its attribute values, and the two strings have to match *exactly* in order for this to work.

```
links[j] = '<li><a href="./player.html?id='+rtndata[j].track_id+'" data-transition="slide" id="'+rtndata[j].track_name+'"><h3>'+rtndata[j].track_name+'</h3><p><strong>'+rtndata[j].artist_name+'</strong></p><p>'+rtndata[j].genre_name+'</p></a></li>';
```

[**Proof of solution**](http://jsbin.com/avibon/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work accurately

```
.done(function(){ 
        $('ul').children('li').on('click', function () {
        var selected_index = $(this).index();
        alert('Selected Index = ' + selected_index);
    });
```

however how can this index be used to get the values within the index such as the href and id